# How to Extract string from XML Property

Tags: xml, powershell, object, properties, output

Using PowerShell, I am attempting to extract the contents of `Value=""` which will either be `Production` or `Training`, from a XML file.  Here is a snippit of the XML file:

```
<ParameterGroup TestRequired="false" Name="CommonSystemConfig" xmlns="http://www...">
    <Parameter Name="DefaultEnvironmentId" Text="DefaultEnvironmentId" ParameterType="List">
        <Value UseFunction="false" Value="Training">
            <ValueList>
                <string>Production</string>
                <string>Training</string>
                <string>Staging</string>
```

I currently have the script as follows:

```html
$XMLfile = "\\$pchostname\$xmlPath"
[XML]$paramBackup = Get-Content $XMLfile

$paramBackup.ParametersInfo.ParameterGroup.parameter | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'DefaultEnvironmentId'} | Select-object -ExpandProperty 'Value'
```

The script is giving me:

```
UseFunction Value      ValueList
----------- -----      ---------
false       Production ValueList
```

How would I just output the `Production` or `Training` so that I could have it populate an xls with the corresponding computer hostname?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry... had to edit for formatting... it is my first time posting here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it now, your object named `Value` has 3 properties, `UseFunction`,`Value`, and `ValueList`, and you need to select the child property named `Value`, which has a value of `Training`.

You could actually just duplicate what you already have, by adding another pipe and select to the end

```
| Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Value'
```

So the full line would be

```
$paramBackup.ParametersInfo.ParameterGroup.parameter | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'DefaultEnvironmentId'} | Select-object -ExpandProperty 'Value' | Select-object -ExpandProperty 'Value'
```

Another way with additional dot-notation

```
($paramBackup.ParametersInfo.ParameterGroup.parameter | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'DefaultEnvironmentId'}).Value | Select-object -ExpandProperty 'Value'
```

Comment: Both of these options work great.  Thank you for the help!